# Hibernate Native Query Left Join vs Postgresql Left join (Why are they different)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I'd like to start by saying that I'd like to think I am pretty proficient sql (10 years of experience) and have ran into a head scratcher. I have the following data

```
Group
Id   Name
1    Group 1
2    Group 2

User
Id  Name
1   Jon Williams
2   Mike Williams
3   Joyce Copper

Product
Id    Name  
1    Cookies     
2    Milk
3    Ice cream

Status
Id   Name
1    Untouched
2    Consumed
3    Partly Consumed

HouseholdProduct
Id     Product     User   Status
1       1          1        1
2       2          2        1
3       3          3        1
4       1          1        1
5       2          2        1
6       3          3        1

GroupHousehold
GroupId     HouseholdProductId
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
2           2
2           3
```

In Postgres, I wrote the following

```
select g.id as Group Id, g.name as Group, p.name as Product, 
    u.name as User
from group g
left join GroupHouse gh on
    g.id = gh.groupId
left join HouseHoldProduct hp on
    gh.houseHoldProductId = hp.id
left join User u on
    hp.userId = u.Id
left join Product p on
    hp.product_id = p.id
order by g.id asc

I get the following data which is correct:

ID        Group        Product        User
1         Group 1      Cookies        Jon Williams
1         Group 1      Milk           Mike Williams
1         Group 1      Ice cream      Joyce Copper
2         Group 2      Cookies        Jon Williams
2         Group 2      Milk           Mike Williams
2         Group 2      Ice cream      Joyce Copper

When I take that exact query and paste it in Hibernate as native query, I get the follow results which is wrong.

ID        Group        Product        User
1         Group 1      Cookies        Jon Williams
1         Group 1      Milk           Jon Williams
1         Group 1      Ice cream      Jon Williams
2         Group 2      Cookies        Jon Williams
2         Group 2      Milk           Jon Williams
2         Group 2      Ice cream      Jon Williams
```

It looks like hibernate is the left joining to the User table incorrectly. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `user` and `group` are reserved words in postgres. [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: this is an example of my database structure. I can't actually show my database stuff due to nondisclosure agreement.

Comment: So please disregard the keywords as i'm not using them.